# Компиляция кода программы на С#

Tags: c#

Новичок в С#, конвертировал код простой программы своей с С++ на это чудесный язык программирования. Получился файл программы GlobalMembers.cs и файла класса. Добавлял в проект в VS2008, не могу оттранслировать, связи никакой. Задача вообще простая, сделать эту программу в консольном виде (чтоб легко запускать в онлайн IDE), что нужно поменять (менял название классов по типу структуры Console program, не получается ничего, множество ошибок). Помогите пожалуйста запустить ее в С Шарп виде.

GlobalMembers.cs:

```
using System;

public static class GlobalMembers
{
    internal static void Main()
    {
        setlocale(0,"");
        const int n = 3;
        int i;
        int[] x = new int[n];
        int[] y = new int[n];
        int a = 0;
        int b;
        double[] z = new double[n];
        double max;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Введите [");
            Console.Write(i);
            Console.Write("] элемент массива X: ");
            x[i] = int.Parse(ConsoleInput.ReadToWhiteSpace(true));
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Введите [");
            Console.Write(i);
            Console.Write("] элемент массива Y: ");
            y[i] = int.Parse(ConsoleInput.ReadToWhiteSpace(true));
            if (y[i] > 5)
            {
                z[i] = (2.5 * Math.Pow(y[i],1.0 / 3.0)) - 6.8 * y[i] + 0.8;
            }
            else
            {
                z[i] = Math.Exp(Math.Abs(y[i] - 2.0)) - Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(y[i] + 5.0));
            }
        }
        Console.Write("Массив X: ");
        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.Write("\n");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(x[i]);
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.Write("Массив Y: ");
        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.Write("\n");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(y[i]);
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.Write("Массив Z: ");
        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.Write("\n");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(z[i]);
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
        max = z[0];
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (z[i] > 0 && i == 0)
            {
                if (z[i + 1] < 0 && max < z[i])
                {
                    max = z[i];
                    a = i;
                    b = 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (z[i - 1] < 0 && z[i + 1] < 0 && max < z[i])
                {
                    max = z[i];
                    a = i;
                    b = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        if (b == 1)
        {
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.Write("max элемент под номером [");
            Console.Write(a);
            Console.Write("] = ");
            Console.Write(max);
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.Write("Чисел окруженных отрицательными элементами не найдено!");
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

========================================================
ConsoleInput.cs:

```
internal static class ConsoleInput
{
    private static bool goodLastRead = false;
    public static bool LastReadWasGood
    {
        get
        {
            return goodLastRead;
        }
    }

    public static string ReadToWhiteSpace(bool skipLeadingWhiteSpace)
    {
        string input = "";

        char nextChar;
        while (char.IsWhiteSpace(nextChar = (char)System.Console.Read()))
        {
            //accumulate leading white space if skipLeadingWhiteSpace is false:
            if (!skipLeadingWhiteSpace)
                input += nextChar;
        }
        //the first non white space character:
        input += nextChar;

        //accumulate characters until white space is reached:
        while (!char.IsWhiteSpace(nextChar = (char)System.Console.Read()))
        {
            input += nextChar;
        }

        goodLastRead = input.Length > 0;
        return input;
    }

    public static string ScanfRead(string unwantedSequence = null, int maxFieldLength = -1)
    {
        string input = "";

        char nextChar;
        if (unwantedSequence != null)
        {
            nextChar = '\0';
            for (int charIndex = 0; charIndex < unwantedSequence.Length; charIndex++)
            {
                if (char.IsWhiteSpace(unwantedSequence[charIndex]))
                {
                    //ignore all subsequent white space:
                    while (char.IsWhiteSpace(nextChar = (char)System.Console.Read()))
                    {
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //ensure each character matches the expected character in the sequence:
                    nextChar = (char)System.Console.Read();
                    if (nextChar != unwantedSequence[charIndex])
                        return null;
                }
            }

            input = nextChar.ToString();
            if (maxFieldLength == 1)
                return input;
        }

        while (!char.IsWhiteSpace(nextChar = (char)System.Console.Read()))
        {
            input += nextChar;
            if (maxFieldLength == input.Length)
                return input;
        }

        return input;
    }
}
```

Comment: что за ошибки-то?

Comment: из того, что сразу бросается в глаза идет попытка использовать функции которых нет, как минимум setlocale и system

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/S1qe_TNsw - ошибки следующего плана в компиляторе

Comment: По ссылке видно только один файл

Comment: В VS studio я добавлял оба. Ошибки следующие: ------ Построение начато: проект: 
C:\Users\SLAVEK\Desktop\kurs_code\ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleInput.cs(42,84): ошибка CS0241: Спецификаторы параметров по умолчанию не разрешены

Comment: выдели в коде строку `42` на которую ругается

Comment: Cтрочка из файла класса:  public static string ScanfRead(string unwantedSequence = null, int maxFieldLength = -1)
 {

Comment: А почему используется 2008 студия? Какая версия framework используется? Какая версия языка?

Comment: frame 3.5 и С# 4.0. Потому что аналогов нет. Раньше вообще все через онлайн делали.

Comment: В смысле аналогов нет? В общем для этих версий могут еще не работать параметры по умолчанию, делай перегрузки функций. Либо обнови студию и версию языка и фреймворка

Comment: В сишарпе main() должен быть в Program.cs

Comment: @4per, не обязательно

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @tilandiya, даже судя по всему достаточно просто до framework 4 обновить

Comment: Framework 3.5 - 12 лет назад вышел в релиз. Зачем так жестоко то? VS2019 накатить с [офф сайта](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/) - делов 20 минут. И пилить код под модный .NET 5 можно будет.

Comment: Аппаратные возможности не позволяют

Comment: @4per не main(), а Main(). И как заметил @Grundy♦ не обязательно в Progrm.cs

Comment: @tilandiya Windows XP/2000 чтоли? В 2019 студии можно собирать проекты даже под .NET Framework 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Поправил несколько ошибок

```cs
public static class GlobalMembers
{
    internal static void Main()
    {
        const int n = 3;
        int i;
        int[] x = new int[n];
        int[] y = new int[n];
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        double[] z = new double[n];
        double max;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Введите [");
            Console.Write(i);
            Console.Write("] элемент массива X: ");
            x[i] = int.Parse(ConsoleInput.ReadToWhiteSpace(true));
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Введите [");
            Console.Write(i);
            Console.Write("] элемент массива Y: ");
            y[i] = int.Parse(ConsoleInput.ReadToWhiteSpace(true));
            if (y[i] > 5)
            {
                z[i] = (2.5 * Math.Pow(y[i], 1.0 / 3.0)) - 6.8 * y[i] + 0.8;
            }
            else
            {
                z[i] = Math.Exp(Math.Abs(y[i] - 2.0)) - Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(y[i] + 5.0));
            }
        }
        Console.Write("Массив X: ");
        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.Write("\n");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(x[i]);
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.Write("Массив Y: ");
        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.Write("\n");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(y[i]);
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.Write("Массив Z: ");
        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.Write("\n");
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(z[i]);
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
        max = z[0];
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (z[i] > 0 && i == 0)
            {
                if (z[i + 1] < 0 && max < z[i])
                {
                    max = z[i];
                    a = i;
                    b = 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (z[i - 1] < 0 && z[i + 1] < 0 && max < z[i])
                {
                    max = z[i];
                    a = i;
                    b = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        if (b == 1)
        {
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.Write("max элемент под номером [");
            Console.Write(a);
            Console.Write("] = ");
            Console.Write(max);
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.Write("Чисел окруженных отрицательными элементами не найдено!");
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Второй класс вообще без изменений собрался

```cs
internal static class ConsoleInput
{
    private static bool goodLastRead = false;
    public static bool LastReadWasGood
    {
        get
        {
            return goodLastRead;
        }
    }

    public static string ReadToWhiteSpace(bool skipLeadingWhiteSpace)
    {
        string input = "";

        char nextChar;
        while (char.IsWhiteSpace(nextChar = (char)System.Console.Read()))
        {
            //accumulate leading white space if skipLeadingWhiteSpace is false:
            if (!skipLeadingWhiteSpace)
                input += nextChar;
        }
        //the first non white space character:
        input += nextChar;

        //accumulate characters until white space is reached:
        while (!char.IsWhiteSpace(nextChar = (char)System.Console.Read()))
        {
            input += nextChar;
        }

        goodLastRead = input.Length > 0;
        return input;
    }

    public static string ScanfRead(string unwantedSequence = null, int maxFieldLength = -1)
    {
        string input = "";

        char nextChar;
        if (unwantedSequence != null)
        {
            nextChar = '\0';
            for (int charIndex = 0; charIndex < unwantedSequence.Length; charIndex++)
            {
                if (char.IsWhiteSpace(unwantedSequence[charIndex]))
                {
                    //ignore all subsequent white space:
                    while (char.IsWhiteSpace(nextChar = (char)System.Console.Read()))
                    {
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //ensure each character matches the expected character in the sequence:
                    nextChar = (char)System.Console.Read();
                    if (nextChar != unwantedSequence[charIndex])
                        return null;
                }
            }

            input = nextChar.ToString();
            if (maxFieldLength == 1)
                return input;
        }

        while (!char.IsWhiteSpace(nextChar = (char)System.Console.Read()))
        {
            input += nextChar;
            if (maxFieldLength == input.Length)
                return input;
        }

        return input;
    }
}
```

Сборка

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: LegacyApp, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  LegacyApp -> C:\Source\LegacyApp\LegacyApp\bin\Debug\LegacyApp.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывод в консоль

```
Введите [0] элемент массива X: 1
Введите [1] элемент массива X: 2
Введите [2] элемент массива X: 3
Введите [0] элемент массива Y: 4
Введите [1] элемент массива Y: 5
Введите [2] элемент массива Y: 6
Массив X:

1 2 3

Массив Y:

4 5 6

Массив Z:

4,38905609893065 16,9232592630193 -35,4571985179197

Чисел окруженных отрицательными элементами не найдено!
```

Принципиально не трогал код, чтобы вы смогли увидеть изменения, которые я сделал, но могу прооптимизировать, если надо.

Я убрал это `setlocale(0,"");` и это `system("pause");`, вместо последнего добавил `Console.ReadKey();`. Вот это `int b;` заменил на это `int b = 0;`, и вот это `for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)` на это `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)`.

Comment: спасибо вам огромное

Comment: @tilandiya если ответ был полезен, отметьте его принятым, галочка слева от ответа